# How to remove Huawei EMUI launcher icon background in Android code

Tags: android, background, icons, huawei-mobile-services

Is there a way to disable the showing of launcher icon background on Huawei's EMUI?

My launcher icon HAS a transparent background, and IS .PNG file.

On every other mobile phone, which don't have EMUI, the launcher icon has transparent background except on EMUI.

Thanks in advance.